# Scheduled queries and clustering

Tags: google-bigquery, dml

It does not seem to be possible to schedule Queries in BigQuery that write to time partitioned **and clustered** target tables (using WRITE_TRUNCATE and a partition decorator): we are getting the error message:

```
Invalid value: Incompatible table partitioning specification. Expects partitioning specification interval(type:day) clustering(siteId,channelId), but input partitioning specification is interval(type:day)
```

I don't understand why this is happening, isn't the clustering specification just a part of the table definition? We also don't need to specify anything extra when performing dml inserts data in an already clustered table. Or is this related to us **not using DML** in the scheduled query?

**EDIT:** The **scheduled query** structure looks like this:

```
SELECT
  reportDate,
  channelId,
  siteId,
  pageType,
  [MORE_COLUMNS_SELECT),
  SUM(timeOnPage) AS timeOnPage_agg,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT( sessionId,
      [MORE_COLUMNS_NESTED)
 ) AS Details
  ----
FROM `project.dataset.viewname` 
WHERE    reportDate >= TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_ADD(@run_time, INTERVAL -1 DAY), DAY)
     AND reportDate < TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(@run_time, DAY)
GROUP BY
    reportDate,
  channelId,
  siteId,
  pageType,
  [MORE_COLUMNS_SELECT)
```

I am writing the results of this query to the target table like this:
**TARGET_TABLE_NAME${run_time-24h|"%Y%m%d"}**

That table is **time partitioned** on _PARTITIONTIME (= Reportdate) and **clustered** on siteId, channelId

Comment: Please [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) with as much detail about your configuration as you can provide. It sounds like a limitation of the scheduled queries feature that it doesn't take clustering into account.

Comment: Context please! What query are you trying to run, can I try to run a similar query...

Comment: Hi @FelipeHoffa, I have added the example pattern to this post. What Elliott Brossard mentions might be right, I am going to check today whether it does work with a scheduled DML statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 23-10-2018, it seems that the BigQuery scheduled query functionality does **NOT** support the WRITE_TRUNCATE loading pattern **in combination with clustering**.

What **DOES** work however, is writing to a clustered target table using a DML statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ss of now **(27th april 2023)** it does seem to work as one would expect:

First you create the table with the clustering and then you can simply INSERT INTO that same table.

```
INSERT INTO `table.name.here`
WITH base_data AS ( .....
```