# Scheduling insert on a clustered table BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following sheduled querie, im just trying to **append** data every day but it is giving me the an error:

```
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',event_date) AS fecha,
  indicador
FROM `TABLE_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND 
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
GROUP BY
  event_date,indicador
```

ERROR:

> Incompatible table partitioning specification. Destination table
>   exists with partitioning specification interval(type:DAY,field:fecha)
>   clustering(indicador), but transfer target partitioning specification
>   is interval(type:DAY,field:fecha). Please retry after updating either
>   the destination table or the transfer partitioning specification.

DESTINATION TABLE:

Table type: **Partitioned**
Partitioned by: **Day**
Partitioned on field: **fecha**
Partition filter: **Not required**
Clustered by: **indicador**

I believe there is a problem with "clustering" is there a way to shedule an insert (**append**) on a clustered table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you might have to be aware of the fact, that Bigquery [clustered](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#clustering_partitioned_tables) tables are not yet supported by **Schedule queries** mechanism approaching *[write](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#write_preference)* operations as was already discussed in this Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890124/scheduled-queries-and-clustering).

As a workaround I would advice two options:

- Using `INSERT SELECT` [DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language) [statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_select_statement) in the initial query
  instead of specifying the destination table when creating the
  schedule query by leaving **Write preference** field as a blank one,
  without triggering any of [WriteDisposition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/WriteDisposition) functions.
- I've used **Destination table partitioning field** as empty composing scheduled query in
  my similar use case, even though the destination table was defined, it helped me to omit the same issue as you've reported as well.

Please let me know whether above mentioned recommendations helped you to solve the issue.