# scheduled query to partitioned and clustered table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have created a BQ table with time partitioned (day/ timestamp) and also clustering data using region and location field.

I have created a daily scheduled query using the query that I ran to create the initial records.  The scheduled query was set to append data to the previously created partitioned and clustered table.  However, scheduled query failed to run with a message below:

> Incompatible table partitioning specification. Destination table
> exists with partitioning specification
> interval(type:DAY,field:timestamp) clustering(location,region), but
> transfer target partitioning specification is
> interval(type:DAY,field:timestamp). Please retry after updating either
> the destination table or the transfer partitioning specification.

The simplified version of the query is below:

```html
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  isYesterday(recordTimestamp TIMESTAMP) AS ( DATE(recordTimestamp) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) );

WITH
  daily AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp,day) day,
    location,
    direction,
    region,
    MAX(metric1) metric1,
    MAX(metric2) metric2
  FROM (
    SELECT
      location,
      timestamp,
        direction,
        CASE
        WHEN area>0 AND area<20 THEN "region1"
        WHEN area>10
      AND area<20 THEN "region2"
        WHEN area>30 AND area<40 THEN "Region3"
        WHEN area=61 THEN "Region4"
        WHEN area=65 THEN "Region5"
        WHEN area=76 THEN "Region6"
        WHEN area>89 AND area<100 THEN "Region7"
    END
      AS region,
      
      SUM(terminalcount0) metric1,
      SUM(terminalcount1) metric2
    FROM
      `statistic`
    WHERE
  isYesterday(timestamp)
--      DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN '2020-07-01'
--      AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 1 day)
        GROUP BY
      location,
      timestamp,
      direction,
      region )
  GROUP BY
    day,
    location,
    direction,
    region)
SELECT
  day as timestamp,
  location,
  direction,
  SUM(metric1) metric1,
  SUM(metric2) metric2
FROM
  daily
GROUP BY
  day,
  location,
  direction,
  region
```

How do I fix this so that scheduled query can run and save the results to the destination table regularly?   Or is it really the scheduled query to the existing clustered table not supported by GCP?

Comment: can you share the query?

Comment: Are you sure that is sheduled query and not BigQuery transfer?

Comment: Hi,  yes I am sure it is scheduled query and not BigQuery transfer.  The query is scheduled to run daily.  I have no problem in running other queries where the destination tables have no partition or cluster. Is this a  limitation of GCP? 

I have added the simplified and shareable query in the question above as can't add it in the reply here due to limited characters allowed.   I couldn't add exact query due to proprietary restriction .

Comment: Anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 3):

There's an answer for this problem here: [61896744](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61896744/scheduling-insert-on-a-clustered-table-bigquery)

You can workaround this problem by adding a view with your select query:

```sql
SELECT field_a, field_b, datetime, date
FROM large_table
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

And creating a scheduled query like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO `my_clustered_table` (field_a, field_b, ...)
SELECT *
FROM `my_view`
```